# How Do I Pass the Parent Object to ICommand from a Button in .NET Maui

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, .net-maui

In .NET Maui I have this XAML Page where I create a collection view from a heirarchy of Objects:

```
OpenJobGroup
    |
    |__List<OpenJob> OpenJobs
        |
        |__List<Position> Positions
```

---

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding OpenJobGroup.OpenJobs}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:OpenJob">
                <Frame Margin="1,10" Padding="5">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Frame">
                            <Grid>
                                ...
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding event_title}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>

                        <Frame>
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding positions}" SelectionMode="None">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Position">
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <VerticalStackLayout>
                                                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding position_title}"/>
                                                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                                <Grid>
//Here is the Button....
//We are in the List<Position> Positions
//This List is in the OpenJob Object
//
//The Button is bound to an ICommand
//I need to send the ICommand the OpenJob Object

<Button Text="Note Availability" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:OpenJobsDetailViewModel}}, Path=NoteAvailabilityCommand }"/>

                                                </Grid>
                                            ....
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

The ICommand is in my ViewModel but I don't know how to pass it the OpenJob object from the XAML

```
[ICommand]
async Task NoteAvailabilityAsync() {
    OpenJob openJob = "how to pass the object here?"
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you can give a `DataTemplate` an `x:Name` but you might try it so `<DataTemplate x:Name="openJobThing" x:DataType="model:OpenJob">` and then for your `Button` binding do: `Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference openJobThing.BindingContext}, Path=NoteAvailabilityCommand }"`

Comment: I can't work out what viewmodel:OpenJobsDetailViewModel is doing in that command. Doesn't seem to correspond to anything in your diagram.  I guess you ought to add a parameter for the position viewmodel to the task.

Comment: @Andy I am following the instructions from this video: https://youtu.be/DuNLR_NJv8U?t=9237 I believe it binds the button to the viewmodel allowing it to access the NoteAvailablityAsync command

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I will try this. Do i then make an observable property called OpenJob and maui will know to bind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://youtu.be/DuNLR_NJv8U?t=8932) tutorial I came up with this markup which works:

```
<Button Text="Note Availability" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:OpenJob}}}" 
            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:OpenJobsDetailViewModel}}, 
            Path=NoteAvailabilityCommand }"/>
```

Comment: I'm surprised that works. My understanding is that `RelativeSource` searches up from `Button`, which is a View, in a hierarchy of views. So I expect it to only find views, not viewmodels or other models. At least that is how it was in Xamarin Forms. Perhaps Maui is smarter!